# An exercise of Liouville's theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f$ be an entire function. Prove that if $|f(z)| > M$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$ then $f$ is a constant function.

It is an easy exercise of Liouville's theorem if $M \neq 0$. But the problem occurs when $M=0$. I am unable to tackle this case properly. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not true when $M=0$.

Comment: Does there exist any entire function $f$ such that $\inf\ \{|f(z)|:z \in \mathbb C \} = 0$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk I fail to follow your comment.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee.: Yes, such a function exists.

Comment: Would you please tell me such an example of a function?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee.: It is a well-known function. Hint: That function is equal to its derivative.

Comment: Yeah its $f(z)=e^z$, $z \in \mathbb C$. Isn't it?